# How do i fix: bind message supplies 3 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 2, error in redux?

Tags: sql, axios, pg

I currently have a query for distance that is working.
I am trying to add another parameter for `type` to order by both parameters.
When I add `type` parameter I receive the error:

> bind message supplies 3 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires
>   2

```
router.get('/:lat/:lon/:type', (req, res) => {
console.log('location GET local route');
let queryText = `SELECT *, distance($1, $2, location.latitude, location.longitude) as distance FROM location ORDER BY distance, type;`
pool.query(queryText, [req.params.lat, req.params.lon, req.params.type])
.then((result) => {
    res.send(result.rows);
    // console.log(result.rows)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not using third parameter that is why you are getting this error:

```
SELECT *, distance($1, $2, location.latitude, location.longitude) as distance FROM location ORDER BY distance, type;
```

You can fix this by either removing third parameter:

```
pool.query(queryText, [req.params.lat, req.params.lon, req.params.type])
```

to:

```
pool.query(queryText, [req.params.lat, req.params.lon])
```

or if you want to use third parameter in order by clause then you need to replace `type` with `$3`:

```
SELECT *, distance($1, $2, location.latitude, location.longitude) as distance FROM location ORDER BY distance, $3;
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to sort only by type and not distance then remove it from your query:

```
SELECT *, distance($1, $2, location.latitude, location.longitude) as distance FROM location ORDER BY $3;
```

Comment: When the 3rd parameter is `$3` the query does work but, it is still only ordered by "distance" and not by "type".  Any Idea as to why it this is still occurring?

Comment: Because your adding `distance` before `$3` in your `ORDER BY` clause. If you only want to order by type then remove `distance`

Comment: When I change my clause order to `ORDER by $3, distance;` I still only get data ordered by distance?

Comment: also I did try to remove distance as a clause but it still does not order by type.

Comment: Please check what are you getting in `req.params.type`

Comment: I am getting which ever type i am selecting in `req.params.type`.